# I have a folder with many tsv files and want to create several dataframes depending on file names

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, csv

I have never posted on this forum before and am not super good in r, but I am at my wits end, having searched for answers and tested solutions all day.
The tsv files all begin with an ID and end in .tsv, several files share same ID. I want to create a dataframe for each ID.
for example, files:
A1.tsv
A2.tsv
A3.tsv
B1.tsv
B2.tsv
B3.tsv
From these files I want to end upp with a dataframe "A" and a dataframe "B".
I have succeeded doing this for one ID using fileNames/lapply/ribindlist, when there are only one ID type of files in the folder, but have failed being able to loop through the whole folder containing all files, creating one dataframe per ID. Any suggestions? Many many thanks!

Comment: Is this a fairly accurate representation of your file name patterns? The IDs are letters, and in the tsv file names they are followed by numbers, with no separator?

Comment: wow, I feel so included and inspired that someone is willing to look at this problem for me. The files all start with the same letter actually, followed by a three digit number (this is a patient ID) without any seperater for example "B108", followed by either a dash or an underscore and more letters and/or numbers denoting a date. But it is the letter plus three digit number that needs to be "grouped". For the resulting "ID" dataframes I will go on to subset depeding on column values and sum etc but I have gotten that to work. thanks again!

Comment: could i use [letter]\d{3} to match the starting letter plus three digits?

Comment: this is an example of the names of the tsv files, they are not all exactly the same though: B106-Y6_S4_L001_R1_001_trimmed.cons.tsv. And then another batch would start with B167, and yet another few start with B217 etc.

Comment: If it's the first 4 characters then you don't need any fancy regex, you can use `substr(x, 1, 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the names of all your files and read them in to a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

## identify the IDs
files = list.files(pattern = "tsv$")
## edited based on comments: first 4 characters is the ID
ID = files |> substr(1, 4) |> unique()

## for each ID, read in all matching files and bind them together
data = lapply(ID, \(x) {
  lapply(list.files(pattern = paste0(x, ".*tsv$")), read_tsv) |>
    bind_rows()
})
setNames(data, ID)
```

This should give you a named list, where each list item is a single data frame for a single ID.

Comment: thanks so much! It looks promising but I am not sure how to single out the separate dataframes in the end. I would preferably end up with a dataframe for each ID (in this case 13) where the dataframe also is called the same ID (the first four characters) as the files

Comment: The idea here is to have a data frame for each ID in a `list`. If you really want them as separate data frames, you can use `list2env()` on the list, but [before you do that read this answer where I explain why it's usually much better to keep them in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061)

Comment: I have been testing so much now, and realize that I only need the files with the matching first 4 characters to "group" ie to make one dataframe. I dont mind if the rest of the name follows so i really dont need to substitute, maybe it is easier just to match the first 4 characters? problem is that some files have four characters followed by an underscore, and some have the four characters followed by a dash. I have tried _|- in the regex without luck.

Comment: If you need the first 4 characters, use `substr(1, 4)` to get them. I updated my answer to reflect that based on your comment on the question.

Comment: Thank!  Maybe I can ask another question? If thats alright. I have several tsv files for each ID, (different timepoints), containing sequence data from targeted sequencing for 10 assays, including columns for family size and coverage data. I want to end up with data that sums coverage for the 10 assays for each timepoint of each ID depending on value in family size column. I did this when I only had a folder containing files from the same ID but want as stated above, this to work with all ID files in same folder.

Comment: It sounds like a regular grouped sum. From this comment I'm not really sure how it would be any different. You can `lapply` or `for` loop over the list to do a grouped sum. Or, if your data is all in the same structure, **don't** put it in a `list`, instead put it all in one big data frame with an `ID` column, and include the ID column in your grouping.

Comment: This is what worked for "one ID"     library(readr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
#make list of file names 
fileNames = dir("path", full.names = FALSE)
listOfTables = lapply(fileNames, fread)

# convert all tables to a big df
df = rbindlist(listOfTables)
#filter rows you want:
newDf = df[df$`Consensus group size` == 0, ]
#subset according to positions
allpos <- subset(newDf, newDf$Position == 844991 | ...
#keep only 2 columns 
C000 <- allpos[,c(1,13)]
#aggregate coverage
Summarized_df <- C000 %>%
  group_by(`Sample Name`) %>%
  summarize(Total_Coverage=sum(Coverage))

Comment: Okay, this is too much for comments. I'd suggest taking my comments into consideration and asking a new question. But if all your data frames are in the same format, seriously consider making one big data frame rather than separate data frames.

Comment: You're using a weird mix of base, data.table, and dplyr. I think things will go easier if you pick one framework and stick with. Maybe post on codereview.stackexchange if you want help with that.